# Django ORM, filter data from 3 different table

Tags: django, django-orm

there are 3 models, how to form a request to retrieve all LocationCompany with a specific city or sector, + DomainService domain + Service service_type, name

````
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    service_type = models.ForeignKey(Service_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30)


class DomainService(models.Model):
        domain = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sercices = models.ManyToManyField(Service, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    long_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(SpecializationService, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30)



class LocationCompany(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    doctors = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, blank=True, related_name='company_doctors')
    domain = models.ManyToManyField(DomainService, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    google_maps_link = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30)
    slug_sector = models.SlugField(max_length=30)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

location_companies = LocationCompany.objects.filter(
    Q(city='some city') | Q(sector='some sector'), # or query for city or sector
    domain__domain = 'some domain',
    sercices__name = 'some service',
    sercices__service_type = 'some service type',
).distinct() # add this to ensure uniqueness
```

Note, best practice is to give your model relations more intuitive names, for example:

```py
class LocationCompany(models.Model):
    domain_services = models.ManyToManyField(
        DomainService, 
        ..., 
        related_name = 'location_companies'
    )
```

This then changes the above query to something like:

```py
location_companies = LocationCompany.objects.filter(
    domain_services__domain = 'some domain',
    ...
)
```